# Django: How to show field HTML in manage.py shell

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get a better understanding of how django works in the background to accomplish tasks, so I am playing with the shell, as I figure that will help me understand the structure better.

Right now, I am trying to figure out, on a component level, how a form field is populated.

For instance, if I have a field of:

```
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How would I, in the manage.py shell, populate that field with a specific user, and show how it is rendered in the template?  For instance, if I have:

```
employee = Employees.get(pk=1)
```

How do I then get employee.first_name in the first_name field, and then show the HTML it would display to the template?  In other words, how do I get from having these two things, to having the prepopulated field that would show in an `UpdateView`.

Comment: You wouldn't. Fields only make sense in the context of a form.

Comment: I understand that, but there is somewhere that the html is parsed.  When the template tag is found, then something has to be called to insert that context for the tag.

Comment: @TimmSimpkins It is the form that renders its fields while accessing the necessary attributes. You can read through the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L200) on github.

Comment: Its kind of a waste of time using the shell to try to understand what django does because doing that will still cover up the magic, instead you're better off searching on google for "github django <subject>" to actually see the source.

Comment: The point is that you can indeed use the shell to see the output of a field *inside a form*; but a field by itself does not have any output.